# Itertools product ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-itertools

I know this question gets repeated a lot but I haven't seen one that deals with this specific problem. I got this function that takes the length of a numpy array, and then takes the cross product:

```
def solve(tab, vacios):
    if vacios == 0: 
        return is_valid( tab ) #Not important here
    large = len(tab)
    for fila, col in product(range(large), repeat=(large-1)):
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I don't really know what to do, so if you could help me it'd be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are producing a combination of `large-1` values every iteration, because that's what you set the `repeat` argument to:

```
product(range(large), repeat=(large-1):
```

but are unpacking values into two variables, `fila` and `col`:

```
for fila, col in product(range(large), repeat=(large-1)):
```

If you pass in a `tab` value with a length other than 3, that'll always be the wrong number of values to unpack.

For example, if `len(tab)` is 4, you produce tuples of length 3:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> large = 4
>>> list(product(range(large), repeat=large - 1))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2), (0, 3, 3), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 0), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 0, 3), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 0), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 1), (3, 0, 2), (3, 0, 3), (3, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 0), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

Either hardcode `repeat` to `2` or don't try to unpack a variable number of values into a fixed number of variables.